# MySQL Одновременное подключение одного пользователя с нескольких компьютеров

Tags: mysql, sql

Можно ли одновременно быть залогиненным на сервере с нескольких компьютеров?

Например, есть юзер `user1`, есть 3 компьютера. Можно ли одновременно быть залогиненным под `user1` с 3 компьютеров?

Comment: Если имеется в виду пользователь БД, то да.

Comment: То есть при логине с двух различных компьютеров при условии, что первый уже залогинен, а второй логинится сейчас, ошибки типа "такой пользователь уже присутствует на сервере" быть не должно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно - ничего дополнительно для этого делать не требуется.

Лимит на количество одновременных подключений есть, но он большой.

Comment: И насколько большой?

Comment: Можно посмотреть запросом show variables like 'max_connections'; На ubuntu 14.04 по умолчанию - 151.

Comment: Еще есть параметр max_user_connections - по умолчанию он равен 0 (нет спец. ограничений).

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Что бы ни имелось в виду.